# Complex POJO validation with PlayFramework

Tags: validation, playframework

Is there an elegant way to validate a POJO parameter with another parameter from the same POJO with PlayFramework ? I'm searching a solution which keep the Play error mechanism.

Exemple :

```
@Entity
public class Page extends Model {

    @Required
    @Min(0)
    public Integer minWidth; 

    @Required
    @Min(0)
    public Integer maxWidth; 
}
```

I need to check that minWidth < maxWidth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a [custom validator](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/validation#custom) and use the @CheckWith annotation.

You could also write a custom annotation (docs on the same page as above), but it's more complicated.

Comment: I read this in the documentation but I the validator or the annotation is applicable to one parameter only. How can I check it with another value from the same object ? I can't pass a dynamic value in the annotation parameter for example.

Comment: The isSatisfied method defined in the Check abstract class (which you extend when you write your custom validator) takes two parameters, the object under test (in your case - Model) and the field under test (let's say the first one - minWidth). Inside the body of your method you then compare minWidth to model.maxWidth..